# Having some issue with laravel collection and a callback function

Tags: laravel, collections, callback, null, anonymous

pro's, amateurs and php enthousiasts.

I am working on a Laravel task wicht envolved dynamic data, collections and graphs.

In order to see what is wrong i kinda need some help, since I can't see it clearly anymore. I should pause and work on something else but this is a bottleneck for me.

I have a collection called orders.
in those orders I have grouped them by date. So far so good. Example below is a die and dump.

Exactly what i need in this stage.

```
"2022-01-29" => Illuminate\Support\Collection {#4397 ▶}
```

Now comes the mweh part.

I have a class called Datahandler

in that class I have three methods in it

simplified version of it:

```php
Abstract Class DataHandler 
{
    /**
     * Handles the conversion to dataset for the chart
     * 
     * @param string $label
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle(string $label):void
    {
        $this->chart->addDataset($this->process->map(
            $this->bind([$this, 'dataLogic'])
        )->toArray()
            , $label
        );
    }

    /**
     * Binds callbacks for the Handler of the class
     * 
     * @param array $callable
     * @return Closure
     */
    function bind(array $callable): Closure
    {
        return function () use ($callable) {
            call_user_func_array($callable, func_get_args());
        };
    }

    /**
     * Defines the fields I need to return to the collection
     * 
     * @param Collection $group
     * @return array
     */
    #[Pure] #[ArrayShape(['total' => "int"])]
    protected function dataLogic(Collection $group): array
    {
       return [
           'total' => $group->count()
       ];
    }
}
```

So in the handle function you can see I am binding ($this->bind()) my $this->process (collection data) to a callback ( $this->dataLogic() ). The protected function dataLogic is protected because every child of this Abstract class needs to have it's own logic in there.

so this function is being executed from within the parent, this is good cause it should be the default behaviour unless the child has the same function. If i do a var_dump on $group in method dataLogic I also have the correct value and the $group->count() also presents the corrent count of said data.

however the return is null. I am not so well trained in the use of callbacks, has anyone an idea on what is going wrong or even a better solution then the one I am trying to create?

forgot to mention the result of my code:

```
"2022-01-29" => null
```

It should be

```
"2022-01-29" => 30
```

Kind Regards,
Marcel

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by doing the following.

I completely removed the bind function and handled my function as a callable for it got the needed solution, is there a better one, sure there is somewhere so any ideas are still welcome, but for now i can continue further.

```php
Abstract Class DataHandler 
{
    /**
     * Handles the conversion to dataset for the chart
     * 
     * @param string $label
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle(string $label):void
    {
        $this->chart->addDataset($this->process->map($this->dataLogic()
        )->toArray()
            , $label
        );
    }

     /**
     * Defines the fields I need to return to the collection
     *
     * @return array
     */
    #[Pure] #[ArrayShape(['total' => "int"])]
    protected function dataLogic(): callable
    {
        return function ($group) {
            return $group->count();
        };
    }
}
```